# iOS - 6755 file attributes changes to 0755 when copied to device - jailbreak

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I want to run the app as root 
Later on I run the app by an indirect script with running this app with 6755 permission setting which that part works and it runs the app.

MyApp.app/MyApp
MyApp.app/MyApp_

I have MyApp file which is a script as follow :
MyApp.app/MyApp :

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$(dirname "$0")
exec "${dir}"/MyApp_ "$@"
```

Which it runs MyApp_ which is the app to be run as root.

This is the file attribute after I ran 'chmod 6755 MyApp.app/MyApp_' on the computer

6755 on computer

-rwsr-sr-x  1 rob  staff  817856 Mar 17 01:07 MyApp_

And this is the file attribute when I copy it to the device 
( using terminal with scp -rp key )
 
0755 on the device after copying !!!

-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  817856 Mar 17 05:07 MyApp_

How ever when I correct the attributes again on the device it works fine and the MyApp_ runs as root! 
But I want to make sure when user installs the app from Cydia and it gets copied via Cydia the same thing does not happen to the user and the MyApp_ attribute doesn't change back to 0755 which causes the app not to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you call setuid(0) in main()?

Comment: Thanks for reply, Yes I did that in the main()  I also did setgid(0);

Comment: You have to chown root:wheel your real app executable (not the script)

Comment: I passed that step, and corrected the question again accordingly, it looks like now the problem is that the running app ( MyApp_ ) loses it's attributes during copying from computer to the device using a FTP client or scp command on the Terminal how ever I used -p to preserve extended attributes ?!

Comment: Try to run *on the device* (through SSH): chown root:wheel MyApp_ && chmod 6777 MyApp_

Comment: I've already passed that step I mentioned in previous comment and the corrected question description, it was resolved by doing chmod 6755 MyApp_ on the device. Please view the question title again for the next obstacle I am facing if you'd like to help, thanks.

Comment: I see, but I anyway advised you to do so. I told you to change the attributes ON THE DEVICE, AFTER COPYING. Which seems to have helped. Now, if you want that chmod to be preserved, after making the Debian package's folder, you want to chmod it once again, and then run dpkg-deb --build. APT *will* preserve your CHMOD, believe me, I have apps on Cydia for which I use this trick.

Comment: Your small tips led me to studying 5-6 hours on dpkg ing stuff and installing new macports, but it was right .deb file is the way to go and it worked by packaging on the device as oppose to the computer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `set*id(0)` to become root unless the process was already running as root to begin with. If you bother checking `errno` you'll find that it will be `EPERM`.

Comment: I don't just setui(0), At the bottom of the my question I explained how I run it.

MyApp.app/MyApp
MyApp.app/MyApp_

I have MyApp file which is a script as follow :

#!/bin/bash
dir=$(dirname "$0")
exec "${dir}"/MyApp_ "$@"

Which it runs MyApp_ which is the app to be run as root.

This is the file attribute after I ran 'chmod 6755 MyApp.app/MyApp_'

-rwsr-sr-x  1 rob  staff  817856 Mar 17 01:07 MyApp_

Comment: That's nice. It still won't be running as root.

Comment: no it doesn't and this is the the log I output -1:setuid(0) -1:setgid(0) - getuid() 501 - getgid() 501
Mar 17 11:45:59 unknown MyApp_[8682] <Warning>: User name : mobile - geteuid() 501 - getuid() 501, getusershell() /bin/sh

Comment: Why do you believe it should be running as root?

Comment: I passed that step, and corrected the question again accordingly, it looks like now the problem is that the running app ( MyApp_ ) loses it's attributes during copying from computer to the device using and FTP client or scp command on the Terminal how ever I used -p to preserve extended attributes ?!

Comment: Of course it does. setuid is potentially a very large security risk (it could even let you root the machine!) so it is dropped when the file is transferred.